# Which of the following statements about determinants are correct?

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices

> Which of the following statements about determinants are correct?
>
> 1. $\det(A^2)>0$, for all invertible matrices $A$
> 2. $\det(A+A^{-1})=\det(A)+\dfrac{1}{\det(A)}$, for all invertible matrices $A$
> 3. $\det(vv^T)>0$, for all column vectors $v ≠ 0$
> 4. $\det(AB^T)=\det((A^T)B)$, for all square matrices $A$ and $B$

Which of the statements are correct? I do not feel secure about which of them that is true.

My answer:
My calculations have given me that $2$ and $4$ are true. Am I correct?

Comment: kindly edit your post to  include your attempts using mathjax.

Comment: Okey. Sorry I forgot

Comment: What do you know about determinants?

Comment: Do you know, for example, that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\cdot\det(B)$ ?

Comment: Sorry I have calculate totally wrong

Comment: How do I calculate?

Comment: $vv^T$ has rank 1

Comment: which means what? Is it true or not?

Comment: Hold on.... I type my answer...

Comment: Okey. Thanks you so much

Comment: 2) is false. Take $A=cI$.

Answer (score 3):

- $\det (A^2)=\det A \cdot \det A=(\det A)^2>0$
- $\det (I+I)=\det (2I)=2^n .\det I=2^n$ whereas $\det I+\frac{1}{\det I}=2$
- $vv^T$ has rank $1$, so its eigenvalues are zero [$(n-1)$ times] and its trace and hence $\det vv^T=0$
- $\det (AB^T)=\det A \cdot \det B^T=\det A \cdot \det B=\det A^T.\det B=\det(A^TB)$

Comment: so the only one that is true is 4?

Comment: it is A*B$^T$ not (AB)$^T$

Comment: see my answer again.  use $\det A=\det A^T$

Comment: 1 and 4 is true then?

Comment: yes...................

Answer (score 1):

For 1, use that $\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$ to find that $\det(A^2) = \det(A)^2 > 0$.

For 2, take $A = I $.

For 3, note that the rows of every matrix $vv^T$ are scalar multiples of $v$. Thus, the determinant will be zero for all vectors with more thant $1$ entry.

For 4, use that $\det(A^T) = \det(A)$, so $\det(AB^T) = \det((AB^T)^T) = \det(BA^T) = \det(A^TB)$.